# map.connect syntax for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, syntax, dictionary

I started learning rails a few days ago and I'm reading head first rails (Dont judge, we all have to start somewhere). It seems to be using rails 2.3 whereas I'm using 3.0....

My question is syntactical.

Routing used to be done with

```
#map.connect 'ads/:id', :controller=>'ads', :action=>'show'
```

My new attempt at it is this

```
match "ads/id" => "ads" :action "show"
```

or

```
match "ads/id" => "ads" "show"
```

Both of which give me errors. For the first one, :action gives me unexpected kend and points to the 'a'.

without it i get missing action.

Can anyone help me out with the correct syntax?

Comment: sorry man.. i'm afraid i'm gonna have to go ahead and judge you.. nah just kiddin :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the format you want to use:

```
match "/ads/:id" => "ads#show"
```

The official [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide is a great resource to learn about routes.

Comment: so in the part where it says ads#show. ads is controller show is action?

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to using RESTful routes. This means simply using

```
resources :ads
```

Which automatically matches `ads/:id` to the `show` action of the `Ads` controller, as well as the 6 other actions. If you *only* want to enable the `show` action, you can use:

```
resources :ads, :only => :show
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
match '/ads/:id' => 'ads#show'
```